# await Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)をDockerで実行した際に、sleepする時間が長すぎると処理が実行されない

Tags: swift

以下の`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`以下の`print("Finish")`が表示されない or エラーになってしまいます。

時間を`1_000`などにすると表示されます。

```swift
Task {
    print("Start")

    do {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    print("Finish")
}
```

```
// output
root@80270fb670dc:/usr/src# swift testSleep.swift
Start
root@80270fb670dc:/usr/src#
```

```swift
Task {
    print("Start")

    do {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000000)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    print("Finish")
}
```

```
root@80270fb670dc:/usr/src# swift testSleep.swift
Start
Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Segmentation fault
root@80270fb670dc:/usr/src#
```

- Windows 10
- Docker
- Swift

  - Swift version 5.5.1 (swift-5.5.1-RELEASE)
  - Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: おそらくsleepの時間が経過する前にプログラムが終了してしまってますね。問題の切り分けのために先頭に`import Foundation`を追加して最後（Taskブロックの外）に`RunLoop.main.run()`を追加するとFinishが出力されるかどうか確認してもらえますか？

Comment: RunLoop.main.run()を追加するとFinishが出力されるようになりました。

Comment: それなら推測の通りですね。sleepで待機している間にスクリプトのプロセス自体が終了してしまっています。待機時間を短くすると出力されるのは運良く全体のプロセスが終了する前にsleepの待機時間が終わっているということでしょう。

Comment: メインスレッドにすればうまくいくという感じですかね？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 解決方法1

`RunLoop.main.run()`を最後の行に追加して、`exit(0)`をTask{}の最後に追加する。

### 解決方法2

コンパイルして、実行

```
swiftc taskSleep.swift
./taskSleep.
```

問題点: コンパイルしなきゃいけない

### 解決法3

`_runAsyncMain {}`内で実行する

```
_runAsyncMain {
}
```

Comment: RunLoop.main.run()はそこでランループを実行して待機するということであって、メインスレッドで実行するという意味ではないです。
スクリプティングで非同期処理を待つのは今のところランループで待機するなどして非同期処理の完了のところでProgramを終了する（`exit(0)`など）動かしていたランループをとめる、などになります。

Comment: `exit(0)`を追加することで、うまくプログラムが終了できるようになりました。ありがとうございます。